# how to install module in correct location or say /lib/modules/`uname -r`

Tags: debian, kernel-modules, make, debian-installer

I have one package for which I want to create debian Package instead of compiling it every time. I tried creating it using dh_make and fakeroot but problem is it just hardcode the location where package will be installed.

So, I need to way tell debian package to understand it should get installed in /lib/modules/`uname -r`, instead of some hardcode version.

Comment: How did you run `dh_make`?  What is you package description (i.e. control file)?

Comment: Yeah, I am using dh_make
control file is not having such information, I think all got decided when I run fakeroot debian/rules binary after dh_make

So, I think I should use something else after dh_make